# How to Execute long running process in Azure WebApp (app service)?

Tags: asp.net, angular, azure

My application is developed using Angular 4 and .NET Core web API which is hosted on Azure as an App service. There is a database query which is taking more time (around 4-5 minutes) and Azure App service gets timed out in 120 seconds, while the application thread gets executed in the background and finishes its work, but since Azure App service thread gets terminated hence it does get reflect on UI.

Is there any way available (any configuration property in Appsettings of webapp) which we can use to extend the timeout of app service.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll have much luck extending the timeout. I don't know why you'd want to anyway - that's a horrible user experience. We recently moved some long running jobs into Hangfire (
https://www.hangfire.io/) and for each iteration we persist a count of processed objects (1 of 10, 2 of 10, etc). Then we check our count w/ ajax calls to display a progress indicator to users. Once it gets to 10 of 10 we reload the UI. Maybe something like that will help you.